# Data warehouse, could a dimention be a fact?

Tags: data-warehouse

We have a data warehouse that, between other things, has to store the product sold by the user.
Everytime a user is added to our system, we have an ETL process that persist the user in .. a DM_CUSTOMER table.
Every time a user by a product, we have a row in FT_SALE, with a FK of the DM_CUSTOMER.
The problem here is that in our dashboard we have to show many KPI related to the number of the CUSTOMER in our DW; how many new customer with daily base, montly, hourly ... and we have to fetch this data from the DM_CUSTOMER.

So, ONE CUSTOMER is a business metric ... so it could be a FACT but ... it is a DIMENSION for SALE table so ... what's wrong with this? is it correct to perform query on DM Tables?
Should I create another FT_CLIENT with a FT of DM_CLIENT ?

NOTE: in out system EVERYTIME a user came into the system, for us is a NEW CUSTOMER, also if that user was already in our system.
We do not perform any kind of deduplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know information that can be calculated from just the Customer Dim table then there is no point building a fact table. However, if you want to slice-and-dice customer information by other dimensions (e.g. date) then it probably makes sense to construct a fact table for customer analytics.

Facts and dimensions are different object types so the fact that you have both a customer fact table and a customer dimension table is not an issue and is, in fact, a common pattern

Comment: Thanks but how can we handle the situation where customers are fact and dim? We use table prefix "DM_" and "FC_" ... so should I create two tables , one for DIM and another for FACT?

Comment: Yes, you create 2 tables

Comment: So you suggest to create a DM table with all attributes and a FT table with only the PK and a date ... got it, tks